# Restore the last MySQL backup file in a folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I need to restore the last Mysql Database file created in the home folder but I am getting an error while trying to run the next command

`gunzip < /home/$('ls /home -t | head -1') | mysql -u root -p123456 mydatabase -h localhost`

The command runs fine if I replace
`$('ls -t | head -1')` for the name of the backup file, but I need to run this on a CronJob every day.

I keep getting the same error:

```
-bash: ls /home -t | head -1: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you put the single quotes in your command?

Should work if your replace

```
/home/$('ls /home -t | head -1')
```

with

```
/home/$(ls /home -t | head -1)
```